# Problem with tls connection between peer and orderer in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: ssl, hyperledger, tls1.2, tls1.3

I have a problem using TLS in my network.
I deployed network with one organisation org1.
It consists:

```
    - TLC CA: ca-tls-org1
    - CA: rca-org1
    - peer: peer1-org1
    - orderer: orderer1-org1
    - cli: cli-org1
```

When I tried to join peer1 to channel, it was ok, but in peer1-org1 logs was:

```
Client TLS handshake failed after 1.117666ms with error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority remoteaddress=172.30.0.5:8051
```

and in orderer1-org1 logs were repeated errors:

```
ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 1.279822ms with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=172.30.0.6:41200
```

My docker-compose files:
peer1-org1:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  fabric-ca:

services:
  peer1-org1:
    container_name: peer1-org1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.4
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1-org1
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1-org1:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=peer1-org1:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/msp
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=guide_fabric-ca
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      # - GODEBUG=netdns=go
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/peer1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/peer1/msp/keystore/key.pem
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/peer1/msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7052.pem
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ENDPOINT=peer1-org1:11051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1-org1:11051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
      # increase timeouts  explore_enrolment/Blockchain-Platform-Network/authomatic-enroll-network/composeRCAs/org1/tlc-ca/peer1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_CONNTIMEOUT=5s
      - CORE_PEER_CLIENT_CONNTIMEOUT=5s
      ## the following setting redirects chaincode container logs to the peer container logs
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true

      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=scripts_fabric-ca

      # Chaincode Build and Runtime Environments
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER=hyperledger/fabric-ccenv
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_GOLANG_RUNTIME=hyperledger/fabric-baseos
      # - CORE_CHAINCODE_JAVA_RUNTIME=hyperledger/fabric-javaenv
      # - CORE_CHAINCODE_NODE_RUNTIME=hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv

      # Couch db settings
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=admin
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=adminpw
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src
    volumes:
      # - ../composeRCAs/org1/tls-ca:/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../composeRCAs/org1/peer1:/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1
      - ../composeRCAs/org1/tls-ca:/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca
      - /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts:ro
      - ../Configs/core.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/core.yaml
      - ../chaincode:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode-external
      # - ./couchdb:/var/hyperledger/couchdb
    networks:
      - fabric-ca
    ports:
      - 11051:11051
```

orderer1-org1

```
version: '2'

networks:
  fabric-ca:

services:
  orderer1-org1:
    container_name: orderer1-org1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.4
    environment:
      - ORDERER_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/orderer
      - ORDERER_HOST=orderer1-org1
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=orderer1-org1
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=8051
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/orderer/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=org1MSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/orderer/msp
      # - GODEBUG=netdns=go
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/orderer1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/orderer1/msp/keystore/key.pem
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/orderer1/msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7052.pem]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_DEBUG_BROADCASTTRACEDIR=data/logs
    volumes:
      - ../composeRCAs/org1/tls-ca:/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/
      - ../composeRCAs/org1/orderer:/tmp/hyperledger/org1/orderer/
      - /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts:ro
    networks:
      - fabric-ca
    ports:
      - 8051:8051
```

cli-org1

```
version: '2'

networks:
  fabric-ca:

services:
  cli-org1:
    container_name: cli-org1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.4
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      # - GODEBUG=netdns=go
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli-org1
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1-org1:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/peer1/msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7052.pem
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/msp
      ## the following setting redirects chaincode container logs to the peer container logs
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true

      # increase timeouts
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_CONNTIMEOUT=5s
      - CORE_PEER_CLIENT_CONNTIMEOUT=5s

      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=scripts_fabric-ca

      # Chaincode Build and Runtime Environments
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER=hyperledger/fabric-ccenv
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_GOLANG_RUNTIME=hyperledger/fabric-baseos
      # - CORE_CHAINCODE_JAVA_RUNTIME=hyperledger/fabric-javaenv
      # - CORE_CHAINCODE_NODE_RUNTIME=hyperledger/fabric-nodeenv
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode-external
    command: /bin/sh
    volumes:
      - ../composeRCAs/org1/tls-ca:/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/
      - ../composeRCAs/org1/orderer:/tmp/hyperledger/org1/orderer
      - ../composeRCAs/org1/peer1:/tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1
      - ../composeRCAs/org1/peer1/assets/chaincode:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode
      - ../composeRCAs/org1/admin:/tmp/hyperledger/org1/admin
      - /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ../Configs/core.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/core.yaml
      - ../chaincode:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode-external
    networks:
      - fabric-ca
```

And my certs genereted by ca-tls-org1. They were used in peer1-org1 and orderer1-org1.

Root-cert in docker variable CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/peer1/msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7052.pem and
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/orderer1/msp/tlscacerts/tls-0-0-0-0-7052.pem]

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            16:c2:e8:6c:49:81:27:9d:51:20:ff:fa:17:fc:e5:3e:6e:da:05:c0
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C=US, ST=North Carolina, O=Hyperledger, OU=Fabric, CN=ca-tls-org1
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun  1 14:32:00 2023 GMT
            Not After : May 28 14:32:00 2038 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=North Carolina, O=Hyperledger, OU=Fabric, CN=ca-tls-org1
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub: 
                    04:0d:b5:1c:01:2a:79:14:97:3d:31:df:3c:6a:28:
                    bb:6a:65:74:55:b6:0c:e8:cf:45:a3:ce:72:a2:e1:
                    2e:70:12:19:f1:ce:d8:21:07:55:3c:38:14:e2:96:
                    e5:9f:73:91:2a:24:ec:cb:5b:5e:d5:c3:b9:19:ab:
                    43:7c:29:b8:35
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:1
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                96:16:16:17:94:D5:E0:2F:7A:37:E8:88:F5:8B:A1:8A:28:77:E9:EA
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                IP Address:0.0.0.0
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:45:02:21:00:95:79:d9:2b:77:8a:c4:67:39:35:89:9f:01:
         fa:81:1b:76:4e:56:21:55:a6:dd:01:d1:6e:82:6e:b6:80:17:
         1d:02:20:31:c0:ed:d0:3a:5c:5e:5e:27:47:ed:89:c1:d1:99:
         c7:5f:5d:9d:d0:47:3a:f7:d3:fa:48:61:cd:b0:39:65:87
```

peer cert used in docker variable CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/peer1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            39:97:62:dd:9d:ca:bb:fe:36:b9:9d:12:63:6f:a7:1e:e1:98:fa:5b
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C=US, ST=North Carolina, O=Hyperledger, OU=Fabric, CN=ca-tls-org1
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun  1 14:32:00 2023 GMT
            Not After : May 31 14:37:00 2024 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=North Carolina, O=Hyperledger, OU=peer, CN=peer1-org1
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub: 
                    04:b0:b5:d1:a0:35:0b:4c:d2:f3:d3:88:d4:fd:8c:
                    a0:85:d1:56:0a:e2:fd:ce:3c:be:a8:cd:8a:7e:64:
                    68:e6:31:7d:3a:9e:27:f9:73:5c:88:34:7e:50:3c:
                    8f:f8:10:90:a1:11:8a:3f:95:fa:64:54:db:22:e3:
                    ed:ad:5d:d7:8a
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                D2:6B:BB:F3:60:0C:EF:AF:8A:6B:3B:AC:8D:00:19:08:CF:29:D4:DA
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:96:16:16:17:94:D5:E0:2F:7A:37:E8:88:F5:8B:A1:8A:28:77:E9:EA

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:peer1-org1
            1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1: 
                {"attrs":{"hf.Affiliation":"","hf.EnrollmentID":"peer1-org1","hf.Type":"peer"}}
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:45:02:21:00:9d:4b:45:c7:f5:3b:fd:26:e6:cc:c3:eb:81:
         b4:1f:62:07:17:f1:48:b8:6e:4c:6b:e2:86:1b:47:33:c3:ea:
         0b:02:20:51:08:5c:7e:b0:39:44:ef:a4:30:3b:ef:42:a4:ea:
         6c:b0:7b:ed:fc:36:b8:91:81:6c:d7:c4:15:22:92:a9:51
```

and orderer cert from docker variable ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/tmp/hyperledger/org1/tls-ca/orderer1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICyTCCAm+gAwIBAgIUBHDGZYlZJY7n+dRswR7DvO4oLjkwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw
YzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAgTDk5vcnRoIENhcm9saW5hMRQwEgYDVQQK
EwtIeXBlcmxlZGdlcjEPMA0GA1UECxMGRmFicmljMRQwEgYDVQQDEwtjYS10bHMt
b3JnMTAeFw0yMzA2MDExNDMyMDBaFw0yNDA1MzExNDM3MDBaMGYxCzAJBgNVBAYT
AlVTMRcwFQYDVQQIEw5Ob3J0aCBDYXJvbGluYTEUMBIGA1UEChMLSHlwZXJsZWRn
ZXIxEDAOBgNVBAsTB29yZGVyZXIxFjAUBgNVBAMTDW9yZGVyZXIxLW9yZzEwWTAT
BgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAASU8w+S5YLXhoFVfdzjgKwtJ1EDwiWUqVI+
22wQizblKfD9p0x4I6YPjEHjyX2XjCtpvGv72SQzTfMfmbeHmW5Fo4H9MIH6MA4G
A1UdDwEB/wQEAwIDqDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwDAYD
VR0TAQH/BAIwADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUbqvD5r6+FQtD/k/DL/rGYa4dApEwHwYDVR0j
BBgwFoAUlhYWF5TV4C96N+iI9Yuhiih36eowGAYDVR0RBBEwD4INb3JkZXJlcjEt
b3JnMTBhBggqAwQFBgcIAQRVeyJhdHRycyI6eyJoZi5BZmZpbGlhdGlvbiI6IiIs
ImhmLkVucm9sbG1lbnRJRCI6Im9yZGVyZXIxLW9yZzEiLCJoZi5UeXBlIjoib3Jk
ZXJlciJ9fTAKBggqhkjOPQQDAgNIADBFAiEAkr+rDgwYcNHBnZaWCk1X6yqYOyfC
0d3SzilrBeQtACECIBuLj9R7lTUYLplFjZM4Le4meURCddQdJMJ/vv/ehgn/
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            04:70:c6:65:89:59:25:8e:e7:f9:d4:6c:c1:1e:c3:bc:ee:28:2e:39
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C=US, ST=North Carolina, O=Hyperledger, OU=Fabric, CN=ca-tls-org1
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun  1 14:32:00 2023 GMT
            Not After : May 31 14:37:00 2024 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=North Carolina, O=Hyperledger, OU=orderer, CN=orderer1-org1
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub: 
                    04:94:f3:0f:92:e5:82:d7:86:81:55:7d:dc:e3:80:
                    ac:2d:27:51:03:c2:25:94:a9:52:3e:db:6c:10:8b:
                    36:e5:29:f0:fd:a7:4c:78:23:a6:0f:8c:41:e3:c9:
                    7d:97:8c:2b:69:bc:6b:fb:d9:24:33:4d:f3:1f:99:
                    b7:87:99:6e:45
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                6E:AB:C3:E6:BE:BE:15:0B:43:FE:4F:C3:2F:FA:C6:61:AE:1D:02:91
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:96:16:16:17:94:D5:E0:2F:7A:37:E8:88:F5:8B:A1:8A:28:77:E9:EA

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:orderer1-org1
            1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1: 
                {"attrs":{"hf.Affiliation":"","hf.EnrollmentID":"orderer1-org1","hf.Type":"orderer"}}
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:45:02:21:00:92:bf:ab:0e:0c:18:70:d1:c1:9d:96:96:0a:
         4d:57:eb:2a:98:3b:27:c2:d1:dd:d2:ce:29:6b:05:e4:2d:00:
         21:02:20:1b:8b:8f:d4:7b:95:35:18:2e:99:45:8d:93:38:2d:
         ee:26:79:44:42:75:d4:1d:24:c2:7f:be:ff:de:86:09:ff
```

Please tell me what the problem is.

I checked my certs and network configuration. I looks like I use wrong certificates. But when I parsed them it looks like ok.